# Ember JSON Loading Issue - Error while loading route: undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ember.js

I have the following very simple file, but when I load it by going to the #/myitem path, in the console I get "Error while loading route: undefined".  The json file contents for testdata.json are shown in a comment at the top of the file.  I have validated through fiddler that the JSON file is coming down OK.  Any help would be great!

```
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-1.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-data.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<!--
Here is what is in testdata.json:

[
    {  letter:"A", frequency:0.01492 },
    {  letter:"B", frequency:0.08167 }
]

-->

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    <h1>Welcome to this Demo!!</h1>
    {{outlet}}
    <h1>Bye!!</h1>
            {{#link-to "myitem"}}My Item Route{{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="myitem">
    <h2>Some Items</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each}}
        <li>{{letter}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">

App = Ember.Application.create({
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('myitem');
});

App.MyitemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var data = Ember.$.getJSON('testdata.json');
        return data;
    }
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: Also your data should not have enclosing `{}`: 
`[
    {  letter:"A", frequency:0.01492 },
    {  letter:"B", frequency:0.08167 }
]`

Comment: @chopper, the commented data was mis-formatted (typo) - the data file itself is fine - sorry about that.  But in fact if the data is good/bad/random key strokes I still seem to get the same error.  The error is raised in `ember-1.4.0.js:3461` which actually reports the message, and the undefined occurs because the error parameter to the error logger is not defined.  This is the strange part.  I have tested with jq 2.1.0 as well, and I get the error in both Chrome and IE11 (both up to date).

Comment: @chopper I should mention that the error is hit from the route `#/myitem` as in `mytest.html#/myitem`

Comment: Could you put together a jsBin?

Comment: @chopper I have posted the sample at https://s3.amazonaws.com/ferkoliblik/errors.html

Comment: I've noticed that if I use ember 1.0.0 then the route error shows the actual route (myitem) that is the issue, but still does not clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Also you should enclose any object returned from `Route#model` in an `Ember.Object`. For example `return dataThatActuallyIsAPromise.then(function(actualData){return Ember.Object.create(actualData);})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be caused by testdata.json not containing valid json.

[RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) states "a name is a string" meaning names need to be in quotes, whereas in your case `letter` and `frequency` aren't quoted.  I've had a quick go at reproducing this locally, and fixing up the quoting appears to resolve the issue.  Try pasting this into testdata.json:

```
[ {"letter": "hello"}, {"letter": "world"} ]
```